# math operators for text fields in views filters

Tags: 7, views

I have a field of type text that contains a number like 10. I want to create a search form with views exposed filters. Since the field is a text, I can't use greater than and less than operators on the field. Is there any way to have such operators for a text field?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a different field of type "number" for that.

You might be able to do something like creating using [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) to create a new field that takes the value of your original field and changes it to an integer with  `$num = (int)$str;`

Comment: I have thousands of submitted contents, so I can't change the field type